# How to get the last day of the month using only month and year?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I want to find out how to find the last day of the month if I only have a year and a month (and no day).

I tried using `EOMONTH()`, but this function needs the date consisted of year, month and day. I can only use `year` and `month` values.

How do I do something like this?

Comment: `SELECT DATEADD(DAY,-1,DATEADD(MONTH,1,yearmonth + '01'))` or `SELECT EOMONTH(yearmonth+'01')`

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Comment: It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers.

Comment: Well since you put SQL Server 2012 now, you should use `DATEFROMPARTS` but there are 4 ways below how to get the same thing. 2012 has a lot more features making a lot of date parsing easier.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you are using Sql Server 2012 then I'd use DATEFROMPARTS.

```
DECLARE @year SMALLINT = 2016
    ,@month TINYINT= 02

SELECT EOMONTH(DATEFROMPARTS(@year,@month,1))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can still use `EOMONTH` even if you do not have a day of the month, just use the first of the month as the day of month is not significant in the input.

```
-- incoming parameters (assuming string but could be int and you could cast them)
DECLARE @month VARCHAR(2) = '11', @year VARCHAR(4) = '2016'

DECLARE @date DATETIME
DECLARE @lastDayOfMonth INT

SELECT @date = CONVERT(date, @year + @month + '01', 101) -- this first part is what you know (year + month), the 01 is just the first day of whatever month appended so the date is valid
-- get the last day of month as a date using EOMONTH and then use DATEPART to get the day of the month
SELECT @lastDayOfMonth = DATEPART(dd, EOMONTH(@date))

SELECT @lastDayOfMonth -- your output on the screen
```

Answer (score 1):

**VARCHAR TYPES**

```
DECLARE @D DATE
DECLARE @YearV VARCHAR(4) = '2016'
DECLARE @MonthV VARCHAR(2) = '12'

SET @D = DATEADD(dd,-1,DATEADD(mm,1,CAST(@YearV + @MonthV + '01' AS DATE)))

SELECT @D
```

---

**INT TYPES**

```
DECLARE @D DATE
DECLARE @Year INT = '2016'
DECLARE @Month INT = '11'

SET @D = DATEADD(dd,-1,DATEADD(mm,1,CAST(CAST(@Year AS VARCHAR(4)) + CAST(@Month AS VARCHAR(2)) + '01' AS DATE)))

SELECT @D
```

**COMBINED TYPES**

some `SUBSTRING` code depending on the format... :)